# Joining to a User History Table

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables. A user history table that logs the date of the change, and all of the relevant info about a user, and then a ticket table that records when the ticket was assigned.

They look kind of like this:

Ticket

```
| Ticket ID | UserID | Assigned At |
|-----------|--------|-------------|
| 1         | 4      | 10/22/2017  |
| 2         | 4      | 10/23/2017  |
| 3         | 4      | 10/2102017  |
```

User History

```
| TimeStamp  | UserID | Tier |
|------------|--------|------|
| 10/20/2017 | 4      | L1   |
| 10/21/2017 | 4      | L2   |
| 10/24/2017 | 4      | L3   |
```

I've tried doing something like this:

```
select t.*
from Ticket t
JOIN (Select u.*
        from userHistory u
        where u.timeStamp < t.assignedAt
        and MAX(u.assignedAt) = u.assignedAt
        group by u.userID
        )as u
on u.UseriD = t.userID
```

I know that that's wrong and I kind of understand why, I just can't seem to understand how to get it to filter for data that's older than the assigned at date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both tables are the same?

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.